# Load Embedded URL to UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview

Can anybody help me on how to load embedded URLs to a UIWebView? The URL may be a URL to Youtube or a simple URL to load any page.

Answer (score 1):

It so simple , Here is the `code for youTube:`

```
    NSString *embedHTML = @"\
    <html><head>\
    <style type=\"text/css\">\
    body {\
    background-color: transparent;\
    color: white;\
    }\
    </style>\
    </head><body style=\"margin:0\">\
    <embed id=\"yt\" src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" \
    width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\"></embed>\
    </body></html>";

    NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML,@"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qe39vPFabuA", 64.0, 64.0];
    [webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
```

If you have to use the **`UIWebView` for loading some website** in it, just use this :

```
    NSString *urlAddress = @"http://www.google.com";

    //Create a URL object.
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
    //URL Requst Object
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    //Load the request in the UIWebView.
    [webView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

Just add this method in your viewWillAppear or according to your requirement.

Comment: Sorry its dynamic the url i am using its may be simple url to load a webpage or youtube url to play video.I need to handle dynamically just embedded url or load if its simple its load page or its load youtube.

Comment: @user191727 Its simple dude, use NSString *urlAddress = youStringVariable; where youStringVariable will contain the url.